# I uploaded a few big files with ftp and they're corrupted/incomplete

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I used FileZilla to upload big files and I just left it there to do its things, I shouldn't have.

Today I checked how it was going and apparently every upload failed at the end with an error like this one:

```
Error: Connection Timed Out
Error: File transfer failed after transferring 786.432.000 bytes in 11572 seconds
```

That's the size of the whole file, here's the [current status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5rwC.jpg) (up: ftp server, down: my pc) afiliasaga5th_ak isn't corrupted, I uploaded from my phone lol so it's probably FileZilla's fault, afiliasaga5th_ad and afiliasaga5th_ag have a different filesize because they're still uploading.
The other files probably miss something at the end, can I fix it? Like with a patch or something? I don't really want to upload 8GB with my 100KB/s upload again...

Edit: apparently it does that with smaller files too.

Comment: You will have to upload the entire file again.

Comment: Damn. I'll try with smaller parts.